# Looking for a good beginners guide for SSO and HAProxy (keyloak, authelia..)

Tags: haproxy, single-sign-on

Im using haproxy now for several years and im very happy... (After i experienced with traefik...) Now i want to put some of my docker-microservices (hedgedoc etc) in the internet. But i want to have some auth before. I also experienced with basic-auth but its annoying(browser is asking every day) and not working very well with some of my services. I have tried authelia but cant get it working.(Do i have to make a dns-record for auth.$DOMAIN and a backend in haproxy??) 
It seems like there is no good guide for integrating sso into haproxy step by step and theres no good graph which explains exactly how authentication works.